# Setting up VPN connection for devices behind firewall

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am new to network security concepts and I want to know how to set up a VPN connection to a home network. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/60774/connect-to-your-home-network-from-anywhere-with-openvpn-and-tomato/) but still unable to connect. My router has onboard Tomato VPN and OpenVPN. Given that the router resides behind a firewall I am unable to configure NAT and set up Port forwarding. How can I configure a VPN link?

**Update:**

**Traceroute on client side reveals:**

```
1 client's LAN IP
2. next hop
3........
..
8 THE_EXTERNAL_IP    server's external IP (defined as external by server's DDNS)
```

---

**Traceroute from server side:**

```
1. 192.168.1.1
2. 10.*.*.*
3. THE_EXTERNAL_IP
```

**Update 2:**

The network topology is considered in this case more or less a black box. I found an article which denotes [technique](http://www.bford.info/pub/net/p2pnat/) to enable Skype get [through firewalls](http://makezine.com/2007/06/01/udp-hole-punching-how-skype-ge/). As I understand the current scenario of setting VPN for 2 hosts behind firewall is pretty common. I would like to know what's the best practices and how to apply it.

Comment: You will have to provide more details.  What router are you currently using, manufacturer and model?  What portion of the link is currently failing?

Comment: You are still giving us nothing to work with. We would need more details on the network topology to help. But even if you supplied that, your question is not on-topic for this site. This is a networking question.